# Encrypt / secure short string to long

Tags: java, c#, encryption, encoding, rc2-cipher

I would like to encrypt / secure input string in the following format "AB123456789000" (two letters and 12 digits) so that the secured "version" can be stored as long (number) in the database.

I have tried RC2 encryption but it gives me 128 bit which does not fit in 64 bit long.

Comment: Two sixteen bit letters and then 12 4 bit digits is more than 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I must have a little rant.

1. RC2 is outdated and insecure (cryptographic weaknesses found), see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2). Use it on your own risk.
2. Why NOT use good cryptography? You want something *secure*, so just encrypt stuff with AES for example. I don't understand the argument that the resulting encryption has to a 64-bit long. In both Java and C# the standard libraries for encryption all work on `byte[]`, no need to represent it as one `long`. Every databasesystem should also be able to save binary blobs.

Back to getting your input size down to under 64 bit.

Using ASCII, your 14-letter long string would be 14 bytes (= 112) bits, its encryption won't fit in 64 bits without compressing. You can cheat by saying that the format **must be** 2 letters and then 12 digits . For encoding, you'd take the first two letters verbatim in their ASCII representation. That would be 2*8 bit = 16 bit. Then take 12 digits as a whole number, e.g. `123456789000 = 0x1cbe991a08` which is 5 bytes (= 40 bit, it fits in a `long`). The biggest possible number here is `9999999999` which is `0xe8d4a50fff`, so everything can still be saved in 5 bytes.

Alltogether we would have 2*8 bit + 5*8 bit = 56 bit, which is small enough to be fitting in one block of the RC2 encryption, which is 64 bit. You can set the last byte to `0x00`.

So, in short, the 2 bytes of the encoded version of your plaintext would represent the ASCII value of these two letters, then the the next 5 bytes would be the number as a `long`.

For example,
`AB123456789000` would be as such be encoded to `0x41421cbe991a08` (`'A' = 0x41, B = 0x42`, then `123456789000 = 0x1cbe991a08`). You can write encoding and decoding functions in both Java and C# to realize this.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding to 64 bit could be done pretty simple:

```
public static long toId(String id) {
    long numPart = Long.parseLong(id.substring(2));
    long letterPart = Long.parseLong(id.substring(0, 2), 36);

    long res = (letterPart << 40) | numPart;

    System.out.println("Ids: " + id + " -> " + res);

    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    toId("AB123456789000");
    toId("AA000000000000");
    toId("AA999999999999");
    toId("ZZ000000000000");
    toId("ZZ999999999999");
}
```

Result

```
Ids: AB123456789000 -> 408042270693896
Ids: AA000000000000 -> 406819302277120
Ids: AA999999999999 -> 407819302277119
Ids: ZZ000000000000 -> 1423867557969920
Ids: ZZ999999999999 -> 1424867557969919
```